# I can't get a website running in apache with debian 11

Tags: debian

I have a Linode, with Debian 11, Apache2, Mariadb and PHP. syscon32.cl, only the Login form appears. When entering the credentials, it does nothing. It does not advance to the dashboard. Linode does not accept .htaccess files. The Apache documentation recommends not using .htacces files. I therefore removed it and added the .htacces data to the Apache system configuration file:

This is my conf file:

```
<virtualhost *:80="">
    ServerName syscon32.cl
    ServerAlias www.syscon32.cl
    ServerAdmin webmaster@servpc.cl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/syscon32.cl/public_html

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =syscon32.cl [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.syscon32.cl
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

    <Directory /var/www/html/syscon32.cl/public_html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/syscon32.cl_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/syscon32.cl_access.log combined
</virtualhost>
```

Can you help me, please.

Comment: What do you want this http vHost to do? It looks like it's a mishmash of a redirect to the canonical https _and_ an attempt to run your application. You should be doing either one or the other, not both at the same time

Comment: How could I get help, this is the first time I've done something like this, I had always activated websites but with CPanel or Hestia, but I had never done it directly without a control panel, like I do on my PC, on localhost it works fine, but with .htaccess

Comment: What do you want this http vHost to do?

Comment: Let's see, I have the same system locally and it works, when you log in and the credentials are true it should redirect to https://syscon32.cl/Administracion/home/ where you activate the side menu to manage the entire website

Comment: I'm not familiar with Linode so I can only offer general advice. I'd start by looking at what is different between your local installation that works and this one that does not

Comment: Apparently this is my problem, but I don't know how to solve it, I have read several documentation files and I have reviewed some forums, which in the end have confused me more than helped me.
this is my error in browser console.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.syscon32.cl/Usuarios/validar' from origin 'https://syscon32.cl' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Perhaps you could show the `.htaccess` file you were originally told to use, along with its instructions for use, and then we can see how you modified the rules to fit the vHost. (Although I don't see why you can't use an `.htaccess` file if that's what the instructions told you to use.)

Comment: Solved, thank you